# How to pass and access data from a dialog component in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog

I have two components Component A and UserActivationDialogComponent. I passed data based on the code below  from Componet A to UserActivationDialogComponent. How do I access that data on my UserActivationDialogComponent ?

Any idea guys ? Thank you .

#user dialog component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-activation-dialog',
  templateUrl: './user-activation-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-activation-dialog.component.css']
})
export class UserActivationDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

#Code after triggering the dialog

```
activateUserDialog(status:string) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UserActivationDialogComponent, {
      disableClose: true,
      data: {
        status: status,
      }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.updateUserProfileStatus(this.data.id);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To access the data in your dialog component, you have to use the
> MAT_DIALOG_DATA injection token:

```
import { Component, OnInit,Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-activation-dialog',
  templateUrl: './user-activation-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-activation-dialog.component.css']
})
export class UserActivationDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: {status: string}) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

[For More Info](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component)